# Satellizer not sending authorization header on some browsers

Tags: php, angularjs, satellizer

I am working on a project using angularjs/laravel. It's a token based project so I am using satellizer to handle that.

It's working fine on my browsers. I tried different machines and browsers here. It's working fine even on my phones. But when I send it to my client, it's not working on his browser. I tried personally using Teamviewer, the problem is that it's not sending an Authorization Token to the server.

Basically login works, when I submitted, I got a success message, redirected to user profile page... then redirected back to login page.

Does satellizer require any client side settings ? As its working on my browsers but not on the my client's.

If my problem needs me to post the code,  you can tell me.

Comment: How / when are you storing the token in local storage? Are you using an interceptor?

Comment: @Jordan I think satellizer do that automatically. Thing is its working on my machines but not on client's. Is there any compatibility issue or maybe you think I should try saving token manually after login ?

Comment: After they login, you should use your browser's inspector to see if it is storing the token in local or session storage. Your client could have disabled that in the browser settings.

Comment: @SunilD. You mean local storage is disabled on his browser ? Actually its not.. Because it saves all my other values that I save manually, in local storage. I just don't see the Token in local storage.

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out why the token isn't getting saved in local storage...

Comment: @SunilD. That's why I am here. What could be the possible reason if somebody faced this problem before ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  Please edit the post and add you relevant code to it.  This will help others to help you faster.

Comment: @Indiandollar did you solved this issue , i am facing same :-( , if there any update please tell me

Comment: @ddw147 My problem was solved on its own, automatically.  So I don't have any solution. Maybe it was some browser issue on client side. I don't know what they did, but the project just started working fine after few days.